# Printing 4-page booklet in Microsoft Word 2010 - page 4 not adjacent to page 1

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, microsoft-word-2010

I am trying to create a four-page booklet in Microsoft Word 2010.  I followed the instructions I found on [this blog post](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/create-booklets-using-microsoft-office-word-2010/), and it has gotten me most of the way there.  But one issue remains.

I don't have a duplex printer, so I plan to print out each side of the page separately and photocopy so that the two are copied onto front and back of the same sheet.  So I what I'm expecting the printer to give me is:

- one sheet with page 4 on the left and page 1 on the right
- one sheet with page 2 on the left and page 3 on the right

Instead, what I get is this:

- one page with *nothing* on the left and page 1 on the right
- one page with page 2 on the left and page 3 on the right
- one page with page 4 on the left and *nothing* on the right.

I haven't found anything online about this problem.  Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: In word what order do your pages go? 4, 1, 2, 3?

Comment: In word they go in "normal" order: 1, 2, 3, 4.

Comment: What happens if you start with a blank page? Does that push everything back a section like you are wanting (and print the first page blank)?